# proving $z_1+z_2 / 1+z_1z_2$ is a real number

Tags: complex-numbers

it seems like i'm completely missing something here.

I need to prove that if

$$\ z_1 \times z_2 \not= -1 \\ |z_1| = |z_2| = 1$$

then

$$\ \frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2} \in \mathbb R$$

so if

$$\ z_1 = r_1(\cos\alpha + i \sin \alpha) \\ z_2 = r_2(\cos\beta + i \sin \beta) \\ z_1 \times z_2 = r_1 r_2 (\cos (\alpha+\beta) + i \sin (\alpha + \beta)) $$

and because $\ z_1 z_2 \not = -1 $ we can conclude that $\ \alpha + \beta \not = \pi $ and also $\ r_1 = r_2 = 1 $

but if we pick two values $\ \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} $ and $\ \beta = \frac{\pi}{3} , \alpha + \beta = \frac{5\pi}{6} \not = \pi$ and we know that  $\ r = 1 $

we can see that

$$\ \frac{z_1 + z_2}{1+ z_1z_2} = \frac{1(\cos\frac{\pi}{2} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{2}) + 1(\cos\frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3})}{1+ 1(\cos \frac{5\pi}{6}+ i \sin \frac{5\pi}{6})} \not \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: How do you know that is not real?  Just take the conjugate and cross multiply.

Comment: You have arrived at $\frac{z}{w}$. I recommend multiplying by $\frac{\bar{w}}{\bar{w}}$ to remove the complex number from the denominator (it will become real). Then hopefully your numerator should cancel to a real number too !

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

You need only to show that for $q = \ \frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}$ holds $\bar q = q$.

Use $\bar z_i = \frac{1}{z_i}$ ($i = 1,2$).